# Keeping UIViewControllers in memory

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiviewcontroller

I am building an iOS app with one of those "hamburger menu" type drawers that open up to a list of options of the left. Like this:

[image: Not actually my app / photo]

Each time you click on an item, for example "settings" it loads a new viewcontroller and displays it on the main view controller. Now, the question I'm wondering is whether or not I should be releasing the viewcontrollers each time a new item in the menu is clicked.

For example:

- You are viewing Inbox
- You click Settings
- I release InboxViewController and alloc init the SettingsViewController
- I make the SettingsViewController the main viewcontroller

I'd like to keep all the viewcontrollers in memory, because I think it would provide for a more smooth transition from one to the next if it was previously allocated, instead of having to wait each time to allocate it.

I am using ARC

Is this bad practice? I might have 6-7 viewcontrollers in memory.

Comment: Are you using ARC?  Are you explicitly 'releasing' objects?

Comment: @Mike I am using ARC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the SDK, Apple makes both choices: `UINavigationController` keeps the whole stack of VCs below the top, while `UIPageViewController` aggressively releases any page except the current one.

This is an example of a "speed/space" trade. Precomputing and caching objects will be faster (once running) but occupy more memory. Releasing more aggressively and building (or rebuilding) will incur some run time cost but occupy less memory.

The question might also be an example optimizing too soon, or unnecessarily. For a handful of typical VCs the allocations are quick and the memory footprints are (ought to be) small. Changing approach will likely have insignificant impact on either speed or space.

I'd start with whichever way is simpler (probably allowing VCs to be released passively is simpler) and see if there's a demonstrable problem that needs solving.

Answer (score 1):

If you consider what you're doing, it's really no different than a UITabBarController. The views don't load until they are viewed the first time, but then are kept "alive" indefinitely. I would think as long as you keep the number of loaded view controllers reasonable (single digits) you'll probably be fine, with the one caveat that if they are all doing some intensive processing/loading/etc., it could become problematic.

Comment: After they are loaded they don't do any additional processing until you view them again and perform an action on them. I guess I'll try running some tests, but from what people are saying, it sounds like it'll be OK.

Comment: I agree, I think you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

I don't necessarily think keeping all the ViewControllers in memory is a good thing, unless the View contains objects that take a long time to fetch (i.e. opening a UIDocument or from a NSURLRequest).

Hope that helps!